# Cannot catch error when extended class is missing

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I try to cycle through all loaded classes, that extend a certain class.
But `is_subclass_of` is throwing an "Class not found" Error, if the reason is an extend class that wasnt autoloaded - and i cannot catch it.

```
        $allClasses = 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php';
            $classes=[];
            foreach ($allClasses as $name => $file){
                try {

                    if (is_subclass_of($name,'mynamespace\\project\\src\\models\\BaseWintypeModel'))
                    {
                        $classes[] = $name;
                    }

                }
                catch(\Throwable $e)
                {
                    echo "caught exception";
                }
            }
```

Error is e.g.

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider' not found
1. in /www/fresh/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php
```

because

```
class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
```

Comment: Try a use to "include" the namespace.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand. Where should i add it ?

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload` to see if that helps.

Comment: i also thought about ```composer dumpautoload``` but it doesnt help for some reason - some parent classes just dont get loaded - but even more strange - i cannot catch the error - and i run php7.2

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i am using PHP 7.2.20

Comment: this looks related: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32995

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32395 This is the related "bug"